# Which program to edit a file in powershell and just the powershell?

Tags: powershell

I see a lot of questions about this but the answers are only about get function and replace function.

Isn't there anyway to edit a file simple a nano or vi in linux, already pre-installed in powershell?

I could think about a thousand of usecase where you don't want to use function to do that. One among many is that you are remoting on a nanoserver and you want to do several changes in a single script file.

Comment: Short answer: ISE is deprecated and VSCode with the PowerShell extension is Microsoft's supported platform for the foreseeable future.  A current benefit ISE has is that it can do remote file editing and is pre-installed on ALL Windows platforms.

Comment: so nothing at the remote nanoserver which I could open in the powershell window then?

Comment: All those things you mention are literally external executables to the shell.  No, powershell doesn't have an external editor for non-Windows platforms.

Comment: True, yeah. Thanks. I'm sure I will need some more help then to open remotely a file and get it in VSCode.

Comment: The shell is not the same thing as the command line interface, or the terminal window. Tools like nano and vi in linux are unrelated to bash or zsh linux shells, the shell launches the tool, and the tool can take control of the terminal window, which is a display available to the remote server. In Windows environments the remote server does not see your local console window as an available display and cannot take over it. All you can do is run a local editor which handles transferring the file content back and forth, or edit via a script on the remote side. Terminals work differently on *nix

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler yes you are totally right. Let me rephrase then: I’m amazed that a so big OS didn’t integrate a cli editor in-house on their shell (which is end-goal of powershell after all). And still my question seems to me valid since no one did ever think to clarify the fact that there is not cli editor in Windows, and apparently none of you take into consideration that at certain point every students in computer science or IT bachelor did ask the same question about it since they are used to *nix. And it seems important to me that somewhere on internet it is clarified !

Comment: What would be the point? You can't have remote CLI terminals in Windows, but you always have a GUI so you can always use Notepad (or a GUI editor of your choice), opening files by SMB share names. Any file editor could be made to open files over a PSSession instead of a filesystem. Restricting the editor to a text console would have no advantages - it wouldn't be running on the remote computer like in *nix, it wouldn't be disconnectable like SSH+Screen sessions are. I have seen this asked and discussed several times before on the internet, including on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am under the impression that you don’t even read what I’m writing. Do you consider that the remote power shell connection (which is cli) from any Windows to a Windows nanoserver 2016 is not remote cli terminals ? Do you consider also that for a service or a program to run on a nanoserver you never need an editor to modify configuration files, remotely? If you are talking about the fact that there has never been a clarification about no cli editor in powershell, well I ve looked for s long time without finding it. Maybe I ve looked badly that long then.

Comment: And if you didn’t seen the point to this, then you’ve never attended to a course about OS management. Because that’s a recursive question in fact.

Comment: I consider powershell to nanoserver is *not* a remote cli terminal. A text editor needs to be able to move the cursor and re-draw a line of text in the middle of the screen as you type. Linux terminals give control to the remote side, so the *server* can reach over the SSH session and move the cursor on your *client* computer to do this. PowerShell remote sessions do not do that, the remote server cannot access or control your local screen, so text editors are impossible inside it. "I want it" or "it would be useful" doesn't change that.

Comment: Okey then if you don’t consider that, then there is no room to discussion. Thanks anyway for your informations

Comment: There is no room for discussion, the technology cannot support it. You could run an editor locally, inside powershell, and have it copy text file data back and forth through the session. But if you are running the main part of the editor locally, there is no benefit to having it inside the powershell console when it could be a full GUI editor, moving data back and forth through the pssession (like ISE does). That's why I say there's no benefit - there is benefit to editing remote files, there's not benefit to keeping alocal text editor stuck in a CLI window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With PowerShell ISE (pre-installed on Windows clients) and vscode with PowerShell Extension and Integrated Console, you can open files in Remote PowerShell Sessions with `psEdit $filetoopen`.

Example

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName nanoserver
psedit C:\nanofile.txt
```

Comment: If you have the new way to do it since it seems that ISE is deprecated, don’t hesitate. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: PowerShell ISE ist deprecated but supported and pre-installed. There is no reason no to use ist for remote administration of nano servers right now. However, both, Enter-PSSession and psedit, work in vscode with the integrated PowerShell host as well.

Comment: I wonder why this gets downvoted. It works perfectly fine and as a matter of fact there is no commandline text editor for PowerShell.

Comment: I don’t know it was not by me. Still didn’t have the time to try it but I believe you.